# Javascript does not have a way of getting a copy of an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, design-patterns, copy

So I have an object

```
var ajaxOptions = {
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            success: function (retval) {
                if (!JSON.parse(retval))
                { 
                    alert("Error occurred.");
                }
                else
                {
                    jQuery('#member-modal').modal('hide');
                    location.reload();
                }
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        };
```

which I want to reuse in several pieces of my code, like

```
var theseOptions = ajaxOptions; 
theseOptions.data = new FormData($('#thisform')[0]); 
$.ajax(theseOptions);
// ... somewhere else in code ... 
var thoseOptions = ajaxOptions; 
thoseOptions.data = new FormData($('#thatform')[0]);
thoseOptions.someOtherOption = "hehehe";
$.ajax(thoseOptions);
// ... somewhere else in code ...
var poopOptions = ajaxOptions; 
poopOptions.data = new FormData($('#poopform')[0]);
$.ajax(poopOptions);
```

The problem is that, as I understand, my `var`s are actually references to the existing `ajaxOptions`, so that, for example, when I run

```
$.ajax(poopOptions);
```

the key-value pair `someOtherOptions : "hehehe"` is still there. In reality I would have to do something like

```
var theseOptions = ajaxOptions; 
theseOptions.data = new FormData($('#thisform')[0]);
$.ajax(theseOptions);  
delete thoseOptions.data; // now ajaxOptions is back to what it originally was
// ... somewhere else in code ... 
var thoseOptions = ajaxOptions; 
theseOptions.data = new FormData($('#thatform')[0]);
theseOptions.someOtherOption = "hehehe";
$.ajax(thoseOptions); 
delete thoseOptions.data; delete thoseOptions.someOtherOption; // // now ajaxOptions is back to what it originally was
// ... somewhere else in code ...
var poopOptions = ajaxOptions; 
poopOptions.data = new FormData($('#poopform')[0]);
$.ajax(poopOptions);  
delete poopOptions.data; // now ajaxOptions is back to what it originally was
```

or maybe I would have to do something like

```
function getAjaxBaseOptions ( ) 
{
    return {
                url: ajaxurl,
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                success: function (retval) {
                    if (!JSON.parse(retval))
                    { 
                        alert("Error occurred.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        jQuery('#member-modal').modal('hide');
                        location.reload();
                    }
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            };

}

var theseOptions = getAjaxBaseOptions(); 
theseOptions.data = new FormData($('#thisform')[0]); 
$.ajax(theseOptions);
// ... somewhere else in code ... 
var thoseOptions = getAjaxBaseOptions(); 
thoseOptions.data = new FormData($('#thatform')[0]);
thoseOptions.someOtherOption = "hehehe";
$.ajax(thoseOptions);
// ... somewhere else in code ...
var poopOptions = getAjaxBaseOptions(); 
poopOptions.data = new FormData($('#poopform')[0]);
$.ajax(poopOptions);
```

This seems a little ridiculous. Is there really no native way in Javascript of making a direct copy of an object? WTF?

Comment: @juvian So I'm right that Javascript doesn't have a natural way of making a copy of an object?

Comment: if by natural you mean a single function to deep copy then no, but you can always make your own. This will be available though in ecmascript 6: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign